# Services.GetValue<T> not finding service

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration

I am attempting to create a custom service for our on-premises SharePoint 2016 server by following the example found at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg193964(v=office.14).  The service is failing during feature activation.  I am attempting to find the current service and create a new service if one is not found by using the following code:

```
var service = SPFarm.Local.Services.GetValue<SchedulerService>();
if (service == null) {
    service = new SchedulerService(SPFarm.Local);
    service.Update();
}
```

The service variable is returning null, but when it attempts to create and update a new service, SharePoint throws an SPDuplicateObject exception stating that an object with the same name already exists.  From what I can tell, the GetValue line is not finding the service as it should.  I was led to debugging the feature event receiver because when I used the same line of code in attempting to create my service application it would also return null.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

I have confirmed that GetValue also does not return the requested service in FeatureDeactivating.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know why this made any difference, only that it did.  I had originally overridden the Name and TypeName of the service (from a different sample code).  When I commented these overridden properties out, it started working correctly.